# What can I use as a Couveture Chocolate substitute?

Tags: chocolate

I have a few recipes for chocolate cakes and cookies but they require couveture chocolate. It is very expensive and I can not afford it. What can I substitute this item with
to get close to the original recipe and taste. Thank you,